# Add Items to Sharepoint list using Client Object Model through Silverlight Not Working

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010

I spent lots of time on the Silverlight access Sharepoint 2010 issue by the following standard code, but the onQueryFailed method is always hit. Please help, thanks!

```
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
        ListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;

        oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ClientList");

        ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(new ListItemCreationInformation());
        oListItem["Name"] = "John Doe";
        oListItem["Address"] = "123 main rd.";
        oListItem.Update();

        clientContext.Load(oList,list => list.Title);

        clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
    }

    private void onQuerySucceeded(object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs args)
    {
        UpdateUIMethod updateUI = DisplayInfo;
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(updateUI);
    }

    private void DisplayInfo()
    {
        MyOutput.Text = "New item created in " + oList.Title;
    }

    private void onQueryFailed(object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'onQueryFailed' handler has a wrong signature. You need to user the 'ClientRequestFailedEventArgs' as second parameter:

```
// Example from msdn:
private void onQueryFailed(object sender, ClientRequestFailedEventArgs args)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Request failed. " + args.Message + "\n" + args.StackTrace);
}
```

If that is not the problem, you will see at least what the real error is.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying a title for the new item which by default cannot be empty. Try adding this:

```
oListItem["Title"] = "My new item";
```

Comment: THanks alfonso! but its not the reason: I renamed "Title" to "Name" and "Title" is actually my "Name".

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe to late but here is how I would do it.

```
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
    Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
    ListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;

    var oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ClientList");

    ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(new ListItemCreationInformation());
    oListItem["Name"] = "John Doe";
    oListItem["Address"] = "123 main rd.";
    oListItem.Update();

    clientContext.Load(oList);


    clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(
              (s, e) =>
              Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => onQuerySucceeded(oListItem)),
              (s, e) =>
              Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => onQueryFailed(e.Message))
              );

}

private void onQuerySucceeded(ListItem item)
{
    MyOutput.Text = "New item created in " + item["Title"];
}

private void onQueryFailed(string error)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Failed {0}",error));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Client Object Model, you always have to use the internal name to access columns.
When you rename your Title-Column to "Name", the internal name still is "Title".

You can do something like this:

```
Field titleField = calendarList.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Name");
Field addressField = calendarList.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Address");

clientContext.Load(titleField);
clientContext.Load(addressField);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
oListItem[titleField.InternalName] = "John Doe";
```